# "Unexpected document received HTML document" with CMIS Workbench

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, cmis

I have configured CMIS in a few SharePoint subsites.

When I access a particular site, CMIS Workbench throws an error:

> Unexpected document received: HTML document

I have another subsite (in same site collection) which is working perfectly with CMIS Workbench.

[image]

**Note: CMIS  feature (Site Features) and Basic Authentication (Web Application) are Enabled.**

Comment: Would you mind posting the CMIS HTTP request and response? You can get them with any network sniffer.

Comment: @Nic it a huge XML response from Post man.

Comment: Then just post the first 100KB or so of the response :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution for this.

1. Create another  Document library in same site. Copy all the files
   from old document Library to a drive in your PC(Use IE and window
   explorer)
2. you will get to know some file will be not copied due to damage or
   another reason skip those files.
3. copy these file to new document library you created in step 1.

### BINGO it worked.